# SwiftLint get "implicit_getter" warning in overriding getter in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftlint

```
extension CGRect {
    var x: CGFloat {
        set { self.origin.x = newValue }
        get { return self.origin.x } > got warning this line
    }
}
```

warning:

> Implicit Getter Violation: Computed read-only properties should avoid using the get keyword. (implicit_getter)

Swiftlint Docs has no Example

https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/implicit_getter.html

How can I solve this warning? Except ignore

Comment: `var x: CGFloat {
        get { origin.x }
        set { origin.x = newValue }
    }` should work. If you look at the Non Triggering Examples at the link you have [posted it is shown at the first example

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping your get and set locations so the get is first. It is normal for gets to come before sets so I imagine swiftlint is only working for that case.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in swiftlint the 

Comment: I've run across this same issue, my get is already first. I've tried expanding to multiple lines as well, no luck.